# GWT compilation Cannot run program CreateProcess error=206

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, compiler-errors

Whole project has been working correctly until I get this compiling error. Googling solutions doesn't help. Full error message and IntelliJ `JAVA_HOME` settings are given below:

**JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Compile error message from `mvn clean install -X`** :

```
    > t\admin-5.0.0-NG-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen 
    D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.admin............;D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.ui.......
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  36.850 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-27T23:31:03+08:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven- 
    plugin:2.7.0:compile (gwtcompile) on project admin: Failed to execute command line :
    [ERROR] [-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m, -Xmx4096m, -classpath, 
    D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.admin............;D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.ui.......]: 
    Error while executing process. Cannot run program "C:\Program 
    Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206,
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (gwtcompile) on project admin: Failed to execute command line :
    [-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m, -Xmx4096m, -classpath, 
    D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.admin............;D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.ui.......]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch 
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute  
    command line :
    [-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m, -Xmx4096m, -classpath, 
    D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.admin............;D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.ui.......]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:552)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute 
    (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
    (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch  
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Failed to 
    execute command line :
    [-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m, -Xmx4096m, -classpath, 
    D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.admin............;D:\project\dk\com.a.b.c.ui.......]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute 
    (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
    (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch 
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while 
    executing process.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:675)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute 
    (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
    (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute  
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch 
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, ▒ļ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒չ▒▒̫▒▒▒▒
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:617)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:655)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute 
    (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
    (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute  
    (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject  
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch 
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, ▒ļ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒չ▒▒̫▒▒▒▒
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:385)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:617)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:655)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine 
    (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute (JavaCommand.java:322)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile (CompileMojo.java:548)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute (CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute 
    (AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
    (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute 
    (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
    (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at 
 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute 
    (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
    (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke   
    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced 
    (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch 
    (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode 
    (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

There's a key message in the error, `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206`. I'm sure I set the correct `JAVA_HOME` address.

Any idea to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your  intellij can not read on C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin\java .
you can try below things , one of them should work

**1)** run intellij as Administartor and then run maven build .

OR

**2)** right click on java folder > properties > security > check for read /write permission on the user with which you have logged in give full permission .
Also in general tab in propteries remove read only .

OR

**3)** move java to do different drive or location and try .

Comment: I've figured out the problem. It was because of a wrong setting  in my pom.xml file.

Comment: @Almett how you are resolve rhis problem by pom?